# Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' (Python)

Tags: python

I'm currently just toying around with defining functions and I'm getting this error. I'm just trying to make an easy function where the user inputs 2 numbers and then it multiplies them together. Also please explain what I'm doing wrong as simply as possible. (I'm a noob)

```
def userinput():
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input("Number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("NOPE...")

def multiply(x,y):
    z = x * y
    print(z)

while True:
    x = userinput()
    y = userinput()
    multiply(x,y)
    again = input("Again? ")
    if again == "No" or again == "no":
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: You can do `if again.lower() == 'no':` and catch all flavors of "no", including "NO" and "nO".

Comment: Also, is all this code inside a function?  Otherwise the `break` inside your last `if` block doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your function `userinput()`, you never return `number`, so python default to `return None`. Thus, when you pass `x` and `y` to `multiply()`, you are trying to do `None * None`, hence the error.

`return number` after the try/except structure in `userinput()`

---

If you also want to check for floats, you can do:

```
while True:
    number = input("Number: ")
    try:
        return int(number)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("NOPE...")
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't bother creating the `number` variable.  Just do `return int(input("Number: "))`.  Then, the `break` is not needed.

Comment: @Haidro also how would I make it so that they could input a decimal? When I run the code now, every time I input a decimal it does not accept it and stays in the loop.

Comment: @Suds2 In your `except:`, you could do another `try/except` structure:. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Ok thanks @Haidro. You are a great help to a programming noob like me.